# update_post_meta add latest data from meta_value array

Tags: arrays, wordpress

I want to add list of color to a product attribute with following code:

```
function wcproduct_set_attributes($post_id, $_attributes) {
        $i = 0;
            foreach ($_attributes as $name => $value) {
                wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $value, $name);
                $product_attributes[$i] = array (
                    'name' => $name, // set attribute name
                    'value' => $value, // set attribute value
                    'is_visible' => 0,
                    'is_variation' => 1,
                    'is_taxonomy' => 1
                );
            }
            $i++;

        update_post_meta($post_id, '_product_attributes', $product_attributes);
    };

    wcproduct_set_attributes($_product_id_data, $my_product_attributes);
```

$product_attributes is an array of colors and $name is pa_color and $value is color name. this function works but it add last color to pa_color.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but `update_post_meta()`, as the name suggests, *updates* meta. There's `add_post_meta()` to add multiple entries. If you want to keep multiple values under one database entry, you'd need to read it first, add your data to it and then update.

Comment: its ok, I want add multiple terms to a taxonomy. i.e. red, green and blue to pa_color simultaneously. $product_attributes is an array of for example 'pa_color' => blue, ...
but it add last term to that taxonomy

Answer (score 0):

The final parameter wp_set_object_terms function need to be true.So,

```
wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $value, $name, true);
```

I must add true at the last parameter.